# Удалить строку таблицы по id с помощью JQuery

Tags: jquery

Как удалить строку таблицы с помощью JQuery? Могу задать id для строчки или, например, порядковый номер.

На странице может быть несколько таблиц, а id - это id внутри таблицы базы данных... Поэтому в рамках страницы id может повторяться, а в рамках таблицы нет...

Comment: Поясните вопрос. Если Вам нужно удаление строки из таблицы на странице, не из базы (и при этом задан id) то и удаляйте как объект: $("#<id>").remove();

Comment: Гм... Наверное, немного не так... На странице может быть несколько таблиц, а id - это id внутри таблицы базы данных... Поэтому в рамках страницы id может повторяться, а в рамках таблицы нет...

Comment: Внесите изменение в сам вопрос.

Comment: На странице не может быть два и более элемента с одинаковым ID. Без каких-либо "а вдруг", "а если", "но мне надо" и т.д.  Для определения группы элементов, используйте классы, data-атрибуты...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет метод [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). Можно либо по `id`:

```js
$("#tr3").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr3"><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

либо по индексу:

```js
$("tr").eq(2).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне подошёл такой вариант:

```
$('#table1').find('tr#id123').remove();
```